# Custom prototype cell xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Good morning,

I would like to create a custom design for my prototype cell and I don't have any idea on how to do that. I have tried to follow some guides or tutorials but I always get some error and there is something that I'm not doing right.

At the moment I'm using the default prototye cell to display the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnYGZ.png

Now I would like to insert a UIImageView, and also 2 UILabels (something like Facebook) with the author and the image displayed in the prototype cell.

How can I do that? Can you show me some example or a good tutorial to follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief list of things to do in order to achieve your goal is:

1) Create a `Cocoa Touch Class File` subclass of `UITableViewCell`

2) Click on storyboard, and change the class of your cell to this one you created

3) Create your `IBOutlets` for the views you added to your cell (UILabel, UIImageView, etc)

4) Then under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, dequeue your customCell and pass data to your views

**For example:**

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
cell.yourLabel.text = @"Your text";
```

These are the basic steps to configure your cell, but you can follow this tutorial here since you are a new iOS Developer, and a Video Tutorial comes more handy for you.

[Creating a Custom UITableViewCell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhJCuDX4GsA)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702) tutorial for how to make custom cell with different ways, and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) that discuss it in details starting from how to use storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

eridb explained you with IBOutlet. If you want to do that programmatically;

1-) Create new UITableViewCell class. (e.g NewTableViewCell)

2-) Create your properties in NewTableViewCell.h

3-) Create and customize your properties in NewTableViewCell.m like that;

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // create label, uiimageview, etc. here
    }
    return self;
}
```

4-) Ok, your custom UITableViewCell class is ready. Now, call it whereever you want to use (e.g NewTableViewController);

```
#import "NewTableViewCell.h"
```

5-) Configure your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath like that;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"myTableViewID";

    NewTableViewCell *cell = (NewTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[NewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    cell.yourCustomLabel.text = @"Label-1 text";
    cell.yourCustomImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test"];
    return cell;
}
```